# UITableView section header invisible

Tags: ios

I made a table with section headers. Now when section == 0 I want no header, when section > 0 I want headers. I create headers by making a UIView and configuring it in code and that works fine, but the first header (section == 0) always appears as something like 18 pixels high, even when my UIView size = (0,0) (or (1,1)) and even when I setHidden:YES on that view. How can I completely hide the first header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with iOS 5.0 it is no longer sufficient to provide a `nil` or a zero-pixel view for the header in the section that you would like to hide: you need to override the `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:` method in your `UITableViewDelegate` as well, and return zero height for section zero:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return section ? actualHeaderHeight : 0.0;
}
```